# Which should have .mjs extension, the importing file or the exporting file, or both?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, es6-modules, mjs

I have a silly doubt. Which file, the `import`ing file, the `export`ing file or both should have the `.mjs` file extension?

Specifically for NodeJS.

I have searched the web but didn't get my exact answer.

*Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 0):

I think just the one that uses the import should be in `.mjs`. From [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_interoperability_with_commonjs):

> An import statement can reference an ES module or a CommonJS module. import statements are permitted only in ES modules, but dynamic import() expressions are supported in CommonJS for loading ES modules.
>
> When **importing CommonJS modules**, the **module.exports** object is provided as the **default export**. Named exports may be available, provided by static analysis as a convenience for better ecosystem compatibility.

Comment: Are you sure? I am in mobile so I can't try it.

Comment: This is what the documentation says. Do you want me to try it for yourself? :P ;)